# Correct use Bash wait command with unknown processes number

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Im writing a bash script that essentially fires off a python script that takes roughly 10 hours to complete, followed by an R script that checks the outputs of the python script for anything I need to be concerned about. Here is what I have:

```
ProdRun="python scripts/run_prod.py"

echo "Commencing Production Run"

$ProdRun #Runs python script

wait

DupCompare="R CMD BATCH --no-save ../dupCompareTD.R" #Runs R script
$DupCompare
```

Now my issues is that often the python script can generate a whole heap of different processes on our linux server depending on its input, with lots of different PIDs AND we have heaps of workers using the same server firing off scripts. As far as I can tell from reading, the 'wait' command must wait for all processes to finish or for a specific PID to finish, but when i cannot tell what or how many PIDs will be assigned/processes run, how exactly do I use it?

EDIT: Thank you to all that helped, here is what caused my dilemma for anyone google searching this. I broke up the ProdRun python script into its individual script that it was itself calling, but still had the issue, I think found that one of these scripts was also calling another smaller script that had a "&" at the end of it that was ignoring any commands to wait on it inside the python script itself. Simply removing this and inserting a line of "os.system()" allowed all the code to run sequentially.

Comment: You can only wait for child processes. You can not wait for grandchild processes.

Comment: Don't use variables to store commands; use functions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to implement a job scheduler with possibly some complex dependencies between different tasks. I recommend to use a job scheduler instead. It allows you to specify to run those jobs whilst also benefitting from features like monitoring, handling exceptional cases, errors, ...

Examples are: the open source rundeck https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck or the commercial one http://www.bmcsoftware.uk/it-solutions/control-m.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm not concerned about the other processes, so long as this particular R script starts after the python script finishes. How it works is I input a number jobs into the python  script and it has a python process with it's own PID for each job I submit. Would that fall into the realm of needing a job scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Make your Python program wait on the children it spawns.  That's the proper way to fix this scenario. Then you don't have to wait for Python after it finishes (sic).

(Also, don't put your commands in variables.)